# How to create a new Leapp actor

Tags: python, leapp

I want to add my own actor to the Leapp workflow, however I’m confused about the relationship of actors, models and workflows objects defined by the Leapp framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Leapp documentation https://leapp.readthedocs.io:

**Actor** is a step that is executed within a *workflow*. Actors define what kind of data they expect, and what they produce.

**Models** are the definition of the data model used in *message* payloads. A **message** is produced by an *actor*, and the payload follows the definition of the *model* it is named after.

**Workflow** describe what work is going to be done and when. It describes a sequence of *phases*, where one phase has assigned filters with which the framework selects *actors* that should be executed from the *repositories* on the system.

For more info about various workflow objects (like phase, repository, stage, tag, and topic) please visit https://leapp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/terminology.html

For in-depth tutorial about creating your own Leapp actor (along with installing all the necessary dependencies for development) please visit https://leapp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials.html.